# How to create dataframe in scala from tables

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create a `dataframe` for two tables in scala and getting `syntax error` when trying to run. Very new to scala.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object testfunction extends App {
val session = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()

import session.implicits._


val sqlContext = SQLContext(sc) 
val df1 = sqlContext.sql("select * from table1")
val df2 = sqlContext.sql("select * from table2")
//trying to call a function 
testfunction("key",df1,df2)
}

//// 
testfunction definition { .... }
```

Please let me know if iam missing any import functions , correct me if the above syntax is not right. learning scala. responses are much appreciated.
Error: error: not found: value SQLContext
       val sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

Comment: Please post the specific error you are receiving.

Comment: And also in what line, that is full stack trace

Answer (score 0):

The current way of doing things would be like this:

```
val df = spark.read.json("/somepath/testweet.json")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("table1")
var df1 = spark.sql("select text from table1")
df1.printSchema()
df1.show()
```

You can't use df1 or df2 without first declaring them with the `val` keyword.
See here for more info: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html